# DOJO reference error: declare is not defined

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was following the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/894af and when I put the same code into my application, I was getting "reference error: declare is not defined". I have following declarations on top of my js file:

```
dojo.require("dojo._base.declare");
dojo.require("dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect");
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?

Comment: sorry, version is 1.7

Comment: Can you reproduce your error on `jsfiddle`? And why you do not use the AMD-style syntax for importing of modules?

Comment: you say you are following the example in the jsfiddle. But no where in the example there is a `dojo.require` call. `dojo.require` is a pre-AMD syntax. You need to be using the AMD syntax as shown in the example. i.e `require(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect"] ...`

Comment: I was including this in my application and my has been with pre-AMD syntax.

Answer (score 1):

With Dojo AMD you can tell which module maps to which parameter, for example `dojo/_base/declare` which is mapped to a variable called `declare`.

However, in non-AMD code you don't have this possibility. In stead of that you have to do the following:

```js
dojo.require('dojo._base.declare'); // Import
dojo.declare(/** Parameters */); // Use
```

And actually, modules in `dojo/_base` are already inside the Dojo core if I'm not mistaken, so you could leave away the `dojo.require()` line in this case.

For the following AMD code:

```js
require(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
  var MyCheckedMultiSelect = declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {
    /** Stuff */
  });
});
```

You can write the following in non-AMD:

```js
var MyCheckedMultiSelect = dojo.declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {
  /** Stuff */
});
```

However, make sure that when you're running Dojo 1.7, that you disable async mode, for example:

```html
<script>
  dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    async: true
  };
</script>
```

This rule applies to most, if not all, modules in `dojo/_base` and several DOM modules, for example:

- `dojo/_base/xhr`: Methods like `put()`, `get()`, ... become `dojo.xhrGet()`, `dojo.xhrPut()`, ...
- `dojo/_base/lang`: Methods like `mixin()`, `hitch()`, ... become `dojo.mixin()`, `dojo.hitch()`, ...
- `dojo/dom`: Methods like `byId()` become `dojo.byId()`
- `dojo/on`: You have to use `dojo.connect()` for this
- `dijit/registry`: Methods like `byId()` become `dijit.byId()`
- ...

---

However, if you're using Dojo 1.7, then you should probably just leave the code in AMD even if all other code is written in non-AMD code. Eventually you will have to upgrade all your code to AMD-syntax, if you're now investing time to convert the code to non-AMD and you later have to convert it to AMD again, you're doing the same work twice.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified code and now I am getting "ReferenceError: CheckedMultiSelect is not defined".

Comment: Because the same applies to all modules... if you're using non AMD you will have to use the module explicitely, for example you have to replace `CheckedMultiSelect`  with `dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect`.

Comment: I did try this and when I try with full name, getting error: "TypeError: dojox.form is undefined"

Comment: That's because you have to wait for the module to be loaded, us `dojo.addOnLoad()` to wrap your entire code.

Comment: Also, read the migration guide: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-17.html You will have to read it backwards to downgrade :p